# CTCI String Compresion Algorithm Alternative approach

Tags: c#, algorithm

I feel the problem was over-engineered in the CTCI book for question 1.6. I think its doable with the same constant space in more readable way as follows. Please comment

```
private static string CompressStringDict(string input)
        {
            Dictionary<char, int> chars = new Dictionary<char, int>();
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                if (chars.ContainsKey(input[i]))
                    chars[input[i]] = ++chars[input[i]];
                else
                {
                    if(chars.Count>0)
                    {
                        output.Append(chars.First().Key + chars.First().Value.ToString());
                        chars.Clear();
                    }
                    chars.Add(input[i], 1);
                }
            }
            output.Append(chars.First().Key + chars.First().Value.ToString());
            chars.Clear();
            return output.Length >= input.Length ? input : output.ToString(); 
        }
```

I am using C# & Dictionary can be replaced with a simple `Tuple` or `KeyValuePair`. In terms of runtime complexity not much of a diff but this is more readable and straight forward. Do you think am I heading in right direction?

Comment: Why do you need here dictionary/tuple/keyvaluepair?

Comment: to keep track of prev chars & their counts. But that's a const space...so..not sure if that's an issue

Comment: What is wrong with ordinary variables?

Comment: Nope..Nothing is wrong, I prefer them too..but the third solution in the book where in we do a repeated work for calculating compressed string length and calculating the string itself is what I thought was over engineered. Instead, we just return the string when first checking for length an use string.length property to verify it and can avoid the re processing of the same logic. that where I thought if this could be more readable and non repeating logic. I know my solution is no way better than the one in the book but trying to make it more readable if at all possible